# Kafka Streams failed to delete the state directory - DirectoryNotEmptyException

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I noticed the exception stream-thread [x-CleanupThread] Failed to delete the state directory with our kafka streams application.  Application uses a windowed state store and is defined as:

```
Stores.windowStoreBuilder(
    Stores.persistentWindowStore(
        storeName,
        retentionPeriod,
        retentionWindowSize,
        false),
    Serdes.String(),
    Serdes.String()).withCachingEnabled();
```

This is not a test issue using topology driver.  This is in actual deployed stream application. Every ten minutes it will try to delete the directory and fail with the stack trace below.  Checking the directory it appears empty using ls -al.  I have also tried modifying the permissions of the directory using chmod 777 with no luck.

Stack Trace:

```
 java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: /data/consumer/0_17
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.implDelete(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:242)
        at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:103)
        at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1126)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils$2.postVisitDirectory(Utils.java:763)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils$2.postVisitDirectory(Utils.java:746)
        at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2688)
        at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2742)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.delete(Utils.java:746)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StateDirectory.cleanRemovedTasks(StateDirectory.java:290)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StateDirectory.cleanRemovedTasks(StateDirectory.java:253)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams$2.run(KafkaStreams.java:794)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Maybe you are hitting https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6647 or https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6655

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, I do not think it is either of those.  I added more details to the question.

Comment: Not sure. If you are 100% sure that the directory _is_ empty, maybe try to delete it manually?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I can delete all of them manually.  Forgot to note I am on a docker container in openshift.  The state store directories seem to be the ones that have been rebalanced away from this processor.  Reading online sometimes DirectoryNotEmptyException is thrown if there is still an open handler.  There is a StateStore::close method but it looks like I should never have to call it in my processor.

Comment: Correct. Kafka Streams will call `close()` automatically. It seems there is an issue with the cleanup logic: (1) KS should delete all files recursively (2) the empty directory should be deleted. When the directory gets deleted, KS will still hold a lock, and would release the lock after deletion. Seems there is some bug in this logic.

Comment: i have a same issue on my local windows-mashine on path tmp\state-store\WordCount\0_0. But i don't even have this path. I only have tmp\zookeeper and tmp\word-count. Very confusing..